How does $\frac1{f(x)}\cdot\frac d{dx}f(x) = \frac d{dx}[\ln f(x)]$?
Perhaps a basic question, as I was told that this was easily solvable using the chain rule, although I can't figure out why:
$\frac1{f(x)}\cdot\frac d{dx}f(x) = \frac d{dx}[\ln f(x)]$
I am wondering how it is that both sides of the above equation are equal.

Do you know the derivative of $\ln(x)$? And the chain rule? State both back to back here in the comments. That might be enough to see the connection and if not then i'll walk you through it

Also you're syntax here is probably wrong it should be $\frac{d}{dx}$ not $\frac{d}{dt}$. I have edited this. if you want me to undo those edits feel free to let me know :)

$[g(f(x))]'=g'(f(x))f'(x)$ In this case, $g(x)=\ln x$

@SidharthGhoshal You're correct, thank you for the edit, and the hint. That made me understand.

@Morten Thank you! I will mark this as the solution if you make it an answer.

Chain rule. One intuition for this is that: $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{f'g +g'f}{fg}=\frac{(fg)'}{fg},$$ by the product differentiation rule.

It's just an application of the so-called chain rule:
Let $f,g$ be differentiable function, then $\frac{d}{dx}g(f(x))=\frac{d}{dt}g(t)_{|t=f(x)}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$
With $\frac{d}{dt}g(t)_{|t=f(x)}$ I mean that you calculate the derivative of g and then you replace $f(x)$ to the variable.
Moreover it's known that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, hence if you put $g(x)=\ln(x)$ and applying the property above you get:
$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x))=\frac{d}{dx}g(f(x))=\frac{d}{dt}g(t)_{|t=f(x)}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{1}{t}_{|t=f(x)}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

An interesting, different way of seeing this holds is to differentiate the product of two functions.
Let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$.
Then $\ln (h(x))=\ln(f(x)g(x))=\ln(f(x))+\ln(g(x))$.
Differentiating yields the following according to your question:
$$\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$
Recall $h=f\cdot g$. Multiplying both sides by $h$:
$$h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
This is just the product rule.

To understand it, you can see this:
$$[(g\circ f)(x)]'=g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$$
Here $g(x)=\ln x$. For example, if I take $f(x)=10x^2,$ then $[(g\circ f)(x)]'=\frac{1}{10x^2}\cdot20x$
Another way to think of $\ln f(x)$:
Since $f(x)$ is inside, we consider $\ln$ first. The derivative of $\ln x$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. But be careful, here is not $x$, but $f(x)$, so we get $\frac{1}{f(x)}.$ Finished? No. Now, we need to consider the inside part and take its derivative. Finally, we get $\frac{1}{f(x)}f'(x).$
